# Controlled Temperature Coefficient of chip resistor

Tags: resistors, voltage-divider, temperature

I am designing and experimenting with current source circuit using Op amp and transistor.

As output current increases, the temperature rises which then makes the output current value to change for about 0.5~1%

I am wondering if I can use resistor voltage divider with two different temperature coefficient to offset the temperature drift.

The temperature coefficient in datasheets are given as +/- 25 ppm, 50ppm, 100ppm, etc..
[image]

I think above means the given ppm value is maximum temperature drift, rather than the exact temperature drift which I can use to design my circuit?

Is there resistor maker or type which I can rely on their temperature characteristics to offset the temperature issue?

[image: fff]

The circuit is for controlling the output current from 4mA to 20mA.

When driving 20mA, as the circuit heats up, the output current decreases.

Chaning R5 with 10ppm resistor helps, but i need more improvement.

I am trying to Use different temperature coefficient for R1 and R2 to counteract this phenomenon.

If there is another way, that would be great too.

Comment: Are you trying to get one resistor to offset the other when the temperature changes? Different coefficient doesn't mean a different direction for the value, they still have the same linear curve as far as I know with different slopes depending on the coefficient. Maybe you can share your circuit to help us understand how you came up with this idea?

Comment: Yes there are such resistors with controlled & relatively linear  tempco but they are not that common like such capacitors used to be- last time I needed them I had to get them custom made and, of course, buy a large quantity. There is probably a better way of stabilizing your source.

Comment: @Cisco25 Yes. I experimented with resistors with different temperature coefficient, but it didn't work as expected. I believe the the temperature coefficient spec is just maximum value. I've added the schematics of the design and how i came up with this idea.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Using different tempco didn't work out as I intended. I posted the schematic, please see If you can find some ways to mitigate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with your circuit is that it is sensitive to transistor hFE. The feedback current is related to Ie of T2 but you care about Ic. T1 may start to compound the issue at higher currents and/or higher ambients by diverting base current from T2. As the temperature of T1 increases the hFE also increases, so the collector current will drop.

Ignoring the function of T1 for now (which I assume is to limit the output current even under fault conditions),  consider replacing T2 with a MOSFET suitable for the power dissipation requirements (at 12V a TO-92 such as 2N7000 may be okay). A darlington pair with two NPN would also be an improvement but at a cost in voltage drop.

Consider adding a 2nd op-amp as a clamp on the non-inverting input of U1 rather than R6/T1. So a diode, op-amp and 2 resistors to create a reference. You will gain a bit of compliance voltage by eliminating R6 so more than 0.4V. You could spend that by increasing R5 to 49.9 ohms which makes the circuit less sensitive to the offset and TCVos of that rather low-end op-amp.